# 組み込み関数 type()について

Tags: python3

**Q1.一覧表示**
・組み込み関数 type()で出力される可能性がある全てを確認したいのですが、一覧として表示させることは可能でしょうか？

---

**Q2.標準モジュール typesとの関係性**
・下記のように掲載されているのですが、「組み込み関数 type()」と「標準モジュール types」には何か関係があるのでしょうか？
[> 標準モジュール types には全ての組み込み型名が定義されています](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-type-objects)

・「組み込み関数 type()」の機能を取り入れ、動的な型生成にも対応するよう拡張したものが「標準モジュール types」？？

Comment: `type()` の引数は1つの場合と3つの場合があるのですが、質問内容的に1つの場合のことでしょうか？

Comment: 「出力される可能性がある全て」といったとき、プログラムの内容は固定していますか？　つまり、特定のプログラムの特定の箇所にある `type()` が返す可能性がある値全てを知りたいのでしょうか、それとも、さまざまなプログラムにおいて `type()` が返す値の総体をご所望でしょうか。

Comment: Q1 に関して、[こういう事](https://trinket.io/python3/5ad9d0b9df)でしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu。type()引数は「1つの場合」について。内容は「さまざまなプログラムにおいて type() が返す値の総体」表示を希望しています(単に確認してみたいだけですが)

Comment: @metropolis。はい。こういう表示をしてみたかったです。ちなみにリンク結果は組み込み型のデータ型を表示しているという認識で合っているでしょうか？ 「import」を使用しているのは単に表示のために使用しているだけであって、importを使用せず「type()」を使用した場合リンク先結果の何れかが表示される？？

Comment: 組み込み型とユーザ定義型を表示していますが、組み込み型だけで良いのであれば `vars().values()` は不要になります。また、import についてですが、python3 では builtin module が外部モジュールになってしまいましたので、`import builtin` が必要になっています。`import pprint` は言われる通り表示のためです。ただし、`set([t for t in list(...` を実行した scope/extent で可視である型だけですので、これを実行した後で import したり定義してあるクラスは含まれません。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございました。大変参考になりました